# Lipophilicity computational prediction

Tags: organic-chemistry, computational-chemistry, biochemistry

Is there a web based (or otherwise) computational chemistry tool which is able to calculate lipophilicity of a given compound?

Comment: http://ilab.cds.rsc.org/ is good but I think requires institutional access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[www.SwissADME.ch](http://www.SwissADME.ch) will calculate several molecular properties, including LogP and LogS.